# How to implement a scoped state container in server-side Blazor when scoped services instantiated twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a fundamental question about server-side Blazor.
Having worked in Blazor WASM and MAUI Blazor Hybrid, I now need to develop a server-side Blazor app and have come across a problem with scoped services when trying to implement any kind of user state container service.
Please correct any of my assumptions if they are wrong.

In short, it seems to be impossible in server-side Blazor to preserve any runtime state in scoped services, because scoped services are instantiated twice. Is that assumption true?

So, let's say I have a class `StateContainer` that I want to add as a service.
In WASM I can add it as a singleton service, but in server-side I obviously need to add it as scoped.

###### IStateContainer.cs

```
public interface IStateContainer
{
    event Action<Settings> SettingsChanged;
    Settings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

###### Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStateContainer, StateContainer>();
```

Now, in my components I want to use this state container to get or set settings.

###### MyComponent.razor.cs

```
[Inject] public IStateContainer StateContainer { get; set; } = null!;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    StateContainer.SettingsChanged += StateContainer_SettingsChanged;
    _loadInitialData = StateContainer.Settings.LoadInitialData;
}
```

With a singleton this works as expected, since there is ever only one `IStateContainer` service.
However, with a scoped service this approach doesn't seem to be possible because scoped services are always instantiated twice, due to Blazor's internal connection and rendering behavior, and components will only inject one of the two instances.

This also doesn't seem to have anything to do with whether prerendering is enabled or disabled.

So, my questions are:

1. Are my assumptions here correct or am I doing something wrong?
2. Is this the intended behavior or an oversight?
3. How can I solve the problem and implement a state container like this?

Comment: Scoped service are instantiated for each connection; not just twice. [Service lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#service-lifetime)  "Server-side, scoped services have a lifetime equal to the duration of the circuit."

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the `OnInitialized` called twice. (prerender+serverInterActive) So it is the problem of prerender.
If you disable the prerender the service should be only called once.

```
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))
```

If not, checking if you are using the global rendermode in App.razor.

```
    <Routes @rendermode=@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false)) />
```

or if you want to keep prerender

```
    [CascadingParameter]HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (httpContext == null)  \\when prerender it is not null
        {
            StateContainer.SettingsChanged += StateContainer_SettingsChanged;
            _loadInitialData = StateContainer.Settings.LoadInitialData;
        }   
    }
```